# Custom Wrappanels to stretch content

Tags: c#, wpf, wrappanel

I'm trying to stretch content that is in a wrap panel, without losing its ability to multi-line. My intention is that if content is smaller than the width of the screen, then it will stretch any undefined content across to fill. Is this possible? Has it been done elsewhere?

The code I wrote so far:

```
    protected override System.Windows.Size ArrangeOverride(System.Windows.Size finalSize)
    {
        if (this.Children.Count == 0)
            return base.ArrangeOverride(finalSize);
        if (FlexibleColumn == null)
            return base.ArrangeOverride(finalSize);

        double totalWidth = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i > Children.Count; i++)
        {
            if (i == FlexibleColumn)
                continue;
            totalWidth = totalWidth + Children[i].DesiredSize.Width;
        }

        if (totalWidth < finalSize.Width)
        {
            Children[FlexibleColumn].DesiredSize.Width = finalSize.Width - totalWidth;
        }

        return base.ArrangeOverride(finalSize);
    }
```

However Children is only for getting, not setting. Any other wany to manipulate it as this point?

Thanks

Comment: Try setting DesiredSize to a new Size object?

Comment: @Belmiris the *DesiredSize* property is get-only.

Comment: Try to use [UniformGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.uniformgrid.aspx). If it is not for you consider overloaing [MeasureOverride](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.measureoverride.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

There are many custom wrappanels: ( http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32629/A-better-panel-for-data-binding-to-a-WrapPanel-in )

Basically you must overwrite the method MeasureOverride

A tip is to set the ItemWidth property that exists in  WrapPanel. eg:

```
if (Orientation == Orientation.Horizontal)
{
    double supostWidth = 0.0;
    foreach (UIElement el in Children)
    {
       el.Measure(availableSize);
       Size next = el.DesiredSize;
       if (!(Double.IsInfinity(next.Width) || Double.IsNaN(next.Width)))
       {
            supostWidth = Math.Max(next.Width, supostWidth);
       }
    }

    double totalWidth = availableSize.Width;

    if (!double.IsNaN(supostWidth) && !double.IsInfinity(supostWidth) && supostWidth > 0)
    {
        var itemsPerRow = (int)(totalWidth / supostWidth);
        if (itemsPerRow > 0)
        {
            ItemWidth = totalWidth / itemsPerRow;
        }
    }
}
```